# Pandas replace(np.nan, value) vs fillna(value) which is faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I'm trying to replace NaNs in different columns and I wanted to know which one is better (faster) for this task, replace or fillna.

Here's some sample code for the fillna option:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2', 'K3', 'K4', 'K5'],
                   'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']})
other = pd.DataFrame({'key_2': ['K0.1', 'K1.1', 'K2.1'],
                      'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']},index=[0,2,3])

result = df.join([other])
```

After this line the joined dataframe  looks like this:

```
  key   A key_2    B
0  K0  A0  K0.1   B0
1  K1  A1   NaN  NaN
2  K2  A2  K1.1   B1
3  K3  A3  K2.1   B2
4  K4  A4   NaN  NaN
5  K5  A5   NaN  NaN
```

and after doing the fillna with

```py
result[['key','key_2']] = result[['key','key_2']].fillna('K0.0')
result[['A','B']] = result[['A','B']].fillna('B0.0')
```

it looks like this:

```
  key   A key_2     B
0  K0  A0  K0.1    B0
1  K1  A1  K0.0  B0.0
2  K2  A2  K1.1    B1
3  K3  A3  K2.1    B2
4  K4  A4  K0.0  B0.0
5  K5  A5  K0.0  B0.0
```

Using the replace instead,

```py
result[['key','key_2']] = result[['key','key_2']].replace(np.nan,'K0.0')
result[['A','B']] = result[['A','B']].replace(np.nan,'B0.0')
```

The resulting dataframe is:

```
  key   A key_2     B
0  K0  A0  K0.1    B0
1  K1  A1  K0.0  B0.0
2  K2  A2  K1.1    B1
3  K3  A3  K2.1    B2
4  K4  A4  K0.0  B0.0
5  K5  A5  K0.0  B0.0
```

As you can see, they both achieve the same result, at least as far as I've been able to test.

I have 2 questions:

1. What kind of NaN does join create (seeing as np.nan is found, I think it's that one, but I want to be sure to catch every NaN created by the join method)
2. Which one is faster, fillna or replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty values in pandas are often represented with `np.nan`, although [it can also use NaT values for datetimes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes), but they are considered compatible in pandas. Also from the documentation linked above:

> The choice of using NaN internally to denote missing data was largely for simplicity and performance reasons. Starting from pandas 1.0, some optional data types start experimenting with a native NA scalar using a mask-based approach. See here for more.

For efficiency, they seem fairly similar:

- fillna

  - time for 10000 runs: 24.815383911132812
  - average time per run: 0.0024815383911132812
- replace

  - time for 10000 runs: 20.818645477294922
  - average time per run: 0.002081864547729492

However, considering the documentation where "some optional data types start experimenting with a native NA scalar using a mask-based approach", it is safer to just use `fillna` and let pandas handle the missing values. Also, from a readability standpoint, `fillna` is shorter and clearer than `replace(np.nan, ...)`.

Comment: Interesting to see how fillna is a bit slower, but more robust. I'd also like to know how to do timed runs, do you know any resources to learn that? Thanks.

Comment: The common way to do it is with the [timeit library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) using either the CLI for timing entire scripts or directly in the code for timing specific sections.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial about that? I've heard about the timeit library, but don't know how to use it...